# Django Rest Framework JWT Unit Test

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, jwt

I am using DRF with the JWT package for authentication. Now, I'm trying to write a unit test that authenticates itself with a JWT token. No matter how I try it, I can't get the test API client to authenticate itself via JWT. If I do the same with an API client (in my case, Postman), everything works.

This is the test case:

```
from django.urls import reverse
from rest_framework.test import APITestCase
from rest_framework_jwt.settings import api_settings

from backend.factories import member_factory

jwt_payload_handler = api_settings.JWT_PAYLOAD_HANDLER
jwt_encode_handler = api_settings.JWT_ENCODE_HANDLER


class MemberTests(APITestCase):
    def test_get_member(self):
        member = member_factory()

        payload = jwt_payload_handler(member.user)
        token = jwt_encode_handler(payload)

        self.client.credentials(Authorization='JWT {0}'.format(token))
        response = self.client.get(reverse('member-detail', kwargs={'pk': member.pk}))
        assert response.status_code == 200
```

But I always get a `401 Authentication credentials were not provided`.

In `response.request` I see the token is there, it's just not being applied I guess.

If I rewrite the test to use `rest_framework.test.RequestsClient` and actually send it to the [live_server](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/testing/tools/#liveservertestcase) URL, it works.

Any help on this?

P.S.: I am aware of `force_authenticate()` and [login](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/#loginkwargs), but I would like my unit tests to access the API the same as the API client will in production.

Comment: You two made my day. Thanks

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Try setting up a new APIClient for this test. This is how my own test looks like

```
 def test_api_jwt(self):

    url = reverse('api-jwt-auth')
    u = user_model.objects.create_user(username='user', email='user@foo.com', password='pass')
    u.is_active = False
    u.save()

    resp = self.client.post(url, {'email':'user@foo.com', 'password':'pass'}, format='json')
    self.assertEqual(resp.status_code, status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    u.is_active = True
    u.save()

    resp = self.client.post(url, {'username':'user@foo.com', 'password':'pass'}, format='json')
    self.assertEqual(resp.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
    self.assertTrue('token' in resp.data)
    token = resp.data['token']
    #print(token)

    verification_url = reverse('api-jwt-verify')
    resp = self.client.post(verification_url, {'token': token}, format='json')
    self.assertEqual(resp.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)

    resp = self.client.post(verification_url, {'token': 'abc'}, format='json')
    self.assertEqual(resp.status_code, status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    client = APIClient()
    client.credentials(HTTP_AUTHORIZATION='JWT ' + 'abc')
    resp = client.get('/api/v1/account/', data={'format': 'json'})
    self.assertEqual(resp.status_code, status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
    client.credentials(HTTP_AUTHORIZATION='JWT ' + token)
    resp = client.get('/api/v1/account/', data={'format': 'json'})
    self.assertEqual(resp.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Comment: Thanks. The new APIClient isn't required as `APITestCase` already has one. But the `HTTP_AUTHORIZATION` did the trick!

Comment: Thank you! The same goes for django-rest-framework-simplejwt which I use. After using `client.credentials(HTTP_AUTHORIZATION='Bearer <token>' ...` (instead of `Authorization='Bearer <token>'...`, everything worked fine!

Comment: I got 401 error for `resp = self.client.post(url, {'username':'user@foo.com', 'password':'pass'}, format='json')` with my correct username/password. I get 200 response with Postman, but 401 with this code.

Comment: The code still works as I run unit testing every day. You should post an independent question with your code to have somebody help you

Comment: I was failing to make it work because I used user_model.objects.create instead of user_model.objects.create_user, in case this happens to somebody. The main difference is that create_user hashes the password before saving.

Comment: @AlexeiMarinichenko did you resolve your problem? I'm having the same problem

Comment: Note you may need to use the username instead of the email for logging in. That depends on your config @jplattus

Comment: Thanks @dkarchmer , I had that part OK, the problem was what Armando said; I was creating users sith create method. Fixed that with create_user method.

Comment: @dkarchmer thanks for the test case brother.. May GOD bless you

Comment: Remember to not pass `user.password` to the request since it is HASHED when saved to the database

Answer (score 35):

The following answer applies if you are using [Simple JWT](https://github.com/SimpleJWT/django-rest-framework-simplejwt) and [pytest](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/contents.html#), and Python 3.6+. You need to create a fixture, I have called it `api_client`, and you need to get the token for an existing user.

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework.test import APIClient
from rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens import RefreshToken

import pytest


@pytest.fixture
def api_client():
    user = User.objects.create_user(username='john', email='js@js.com', password='js.sj')
    client = APIClient()
    refresh = RefreshToken.for_user(user)
    client.credentials(HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=f'Bearer {refresh.access_token}')

    return client
```

Notice that in the fixture above, the user is created there, but you can use another fixture to create the user and pass it to this one. The key element is the following line:

```py
refresh = RefreshToken.for_user(user)
```

This line allows you to create tokens manually as explained [in the docs](https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/creating_tokens_manually.html). Once you have that token, you can use the method `credentials` in order to set headers that will then be included on all subsequent requests by the test client. Notice that `refresh.access_token` contains the access token.

This fixture has to be used in your tests that you require the user to be authenticated as in the following example:

```py
@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_name_of_your_test(api_client):
    # Add your logic here
    url = reverse('your-url')
    response = api_client.get(url)
    data = response.data

    assert response.status_code == HTTP_200_OK
    # your asserts
```

Comment: Got the job done for me, exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Comment: This was most helpful, helped me get through a unit test issue that kept me bound for a couple of hours!

Comment: Any help on this please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76189026/django-how-to-mock-access-token

Comment: Nice! And if you're using pytest-django, the fixture setup can be made even cleaner by using the `admin_user` fixture.

Answer (score 7):

I had similar issue, enclosed I send you my solution just to have more code to compare (tests.py).

```
from django.urls import reverse
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.test import APITestCase
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class AuthViewsTests(APITestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.username = 'usuario'
        self.password = 'contrasegna'
        self.data = {
            'username': self.username,
            'password': self.password
        }

    def test_current_user(self):

        # URL using path name
        url = reverse('tokenAuth')

        # Create a user is a workaround in order to authentication works
        user = User.objects.create_user(username='usuario', email='usuario@mail.com', password='contrasegna')
        self.assertEqual(user.is_active, 1, 'Active User')

        # First post to get token
        response = self.client.post(url, self.data, format='json')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK, response.content)
        token = response.data['token']

        # Next post/get's will require the token to connect
        self.client.credentials(HTTP_AUTHORIZATION='JWT {0}'.format(token))
        response = self.client.get(reverse('currentUser'), data={'format': 'json'})
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK, response.content)
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, since i was using django unit test client, i just created a simple base test class with a bearer token property:

```
import json

from django.test import TestCase
from django.contrib.auth import User

from rest_framework.test import APIClient
from rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens import RefreshToken


class TestCaseBase(TestCase):
    @property
    def bearer_token(self):
        # assuming there is a user in User model
        user = User.objects.get(id=1)

        refresh = RefreshToken.for_user(user)
        return {"HTTP_AUTHORIZATION":f'Bearer {refresh.access_token}'}
```

In my django unit tests:

```
class SomeTestClass(TestCaseBase):
    url = "someurl"

    def test_get_something(self):
        self.client.get(self.url, **self.bearer_token)

    def test_post_something(self):
        self.client.post(self.url, data={"key":"value"}, **self.bearer_token)
```

Comment: But the `client = APIClient()` here is not used

Comment: I get this error : `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10`

Comment: @ashdaily how do you import the function `bearer_token`?

Comment: @EliasPrado I have updated the answer, it was `self.bearer_token` not `bearer_token`.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by @dkarchmer, this is my code working.
I am using a custom user model which the email is used for authentication.
Pay attention to using `email` field for authentication requests.
If I use `username`, the response is `400_BAD_REQUEST`.
The `401_UNAUTHORIZED` usually means the credentials are not correct or the user is not activated.

```py
def test_unusual(self):
        User = get_user_model()
        email = 'user@test.com'
        password = 'userpass1'
        username = 'user'
        user = User.objects.create_user(
            username=username, email=email, password=password)

        user.is_active = False
        user.save()

        obtain_url = reverse('token_obtain_pair')
        resp = self.client.post(
            obtain_url, {'email': email, 'password': password}, format='json')

        self.assertEqual(resp.status_code, status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)

        user.is_active = True
        user.save()

        resp = self.client.post(
            obtain_url, {'email': email, 'password': password}, format='json')

        self.assertEqual(resp.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Comment: Hope this can help @alexei-marinichenko

Answer (score 1):

Postman interacts with your actual database. Django uses separate database for it's test case running. Therefore a new user record needs to be created again inside your test definition before authentication testing. Hope this helps.

Comment: The user is created on the first line of `test_get_member()`

Comment: Thanks @Christof. Make sure password are encrypted just in case. From memory those 2 issues I had faced. Good Luck.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using DRF and simple-jwt and I had to use Bearer instead of JWT in the http auth header: `HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=f'Bearer {token}'`

Full code:

```
def setUp(self):
    username = "tim@me.com"
    password = "strongP@assword!"
    self.user = User.objects.create_user(username, username, password)

    jwt_fetch_data = {
        'username':username,
        'password':password
    }

    url = reverse('token_obtain_pair')
    response = self.client.post(url, jwt_fetch_data, format='json')
    token = response.data['access']
    self.client.credentials(HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=f'Bearer {token}')

def test_post(self):
    response = self.client.get('/some-url/',
                               data={'format': 'json'}
                               )
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from rest_framework.test import APITestCase
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.urls import reverse
from rest_framework import status

from rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens import RefreshToken

User = get_user_model()


class TestCaseBase(APITestCase):
    @property
    def bearer_token(self):
        # assuming there is a user in User model
        user = User.objects.create_user(
            email='test@user.me', password='12345678'
        )

        refresh = RefreshToken.for_user(user)
        return {"HTTP_AUTHORIZATION": f'Bearer {refresh.access_token}'}


class CategoriesTestClass(TestCaseBase):
    url = reverse('categories-list')

    def test_get_list_no_auth(self):
        response = self.client.get(self.url)
        self.assertEqual(
            response.status_code, status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED, response.data
        )

    def test_get_list(self):
        response = self.client.get(self.url, **self.bearer_token)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)`enter code here`
```